# Finding the max value in Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

From the following, how can I get the tuple with the highest value?

```
Array[(String, Int)] = Array((a,30),(b,50),(c,20))
```

In this example the result I want would be `(b,50)`

Comment: You're asking about finding maximum in a RDD while showing an example with `Array[(String, Int)]`. I'm missing the connection between Spark's RDD API and Scala. How big is the input array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `reduce()`:

```
val max_tuple = rdd.reduce((acc,value) => { 
  if(acc._2 < value._2) value else acc})
//max_tuple: (String, Int) = (b,50)
```

**Data**

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(("a",30),("b",50),("c",20)))
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Wanted to understand the syntax - what does acc._2 and value._2 mean?

Comment: it simply means we are grabbing the second values from the tuple, ie. the numbers

Answer (score 2):

If the elements are always tuples of two elements you could simply:

```
Array((a,30),(b,50),(c,20)).maxBy(_._2)
```

As specified in the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#maxBy[B](f:A=%3EB):A).

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this besides maxBy?

Comment: What's wrong with using `maxBy`? It looks like the simplest, most straight forward way.

Comment: I get the following error when I use maxBy:

`error: value maxBy is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, int)]`

Comment: Apologies. I'm new to Spark so I'm still learn the ropes. How can perform this same operation on an `RDD`?

Comment: I do not know and I would not have attempted answering it if it was made clear :) 
If you want to get the most of using SO I suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to spark, I should tell you that you have to use `Dataframe`s as much as possible, they have a lot of advantages comparing with `RDD`s, with `Dataframe`s you can get the max like this:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max
val df = Seq(("a",30),("b",50),("c",20)).toDF("x", "y")
val x = df.sort($"y".desc).first()
```

Disclaimer: as @Mandy007 noted in the comments, this solution is more computationally expensive speaking because it must be ordered

This should work, it works for me at least. hope this helps you.

Comment: if you are going to convert to dataframe's you are better off using the aggregate function `max()`.

Comment: the problem with that it just return the value of one column and we want the whole row

Comment: This solution is more computationally expensive speaking because it must be ordered

Comment: @Mandy007 You're right. I'll update my Answer accordingly

Comment: @Mandy007 I really don't think that's correct. I believe DataFrames have query optimisations such that if you sort, but only request a few rows, it can use a linear time algorithm to find just those top values. To find out, I tested it on my machine; here's [a gist of most of my test code](https://gist.github.com/Multihuntr/4abff90772465b054d634dabd27fa012). As you request more rows, the ordering gets more expensive.

Comment: @Multihunter I just say "This solution is more computationally expensive speaking because it must be ordered" if you have better performance OK

Comment: @Mandy007 But my point is that it doesn't actually sort the whole dataset. So it is neither theoretically nor experimentally more expensive to use order by and .first over reduce (when using DataFrame). I believe your statement is false and is misleading people. Do you have any evidence for your claim? Do you think think I have misunderstood something? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

`reduce()` returns wrong result for me. There are some other options:

```
val maxTemp2 = rdd.max()(Ordering[Int].on(x=>x._2))
val maxTemp3 = rdd.sortBy[Int](x=>x._2).take(1)(0)
```

**Data**

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(("a",30),("b",50),("c",20)))
```

Answer (score 0):

rdd.reduceByKey((a,b)=>a+b).collect.maxBy(_._2)

we can use maxBy on collect like this